# Opposite function of INITCAP()

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Can we do the opposite of the `INITCAP()` function? It sets the first letter of each word to lowercase and rest of the letters to upper case.

For example, `SOMEFUNCTION(abc)` returns `aBC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find a function for [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

```
delimiter //
create function lower_first (input varchar(255))
returns varchar(255)
deterministic
begin
declare len int;
declare i int;
set len   = char_length(input);
set input = upper(input);
set i = 0;
while (i < len) do
    if (mid(input,i,1) = ' ' or i = 0) then
        if (i < len) then
            set input = concat(
                          left(input,i),
                          lower(mid(input,i + 1,1)),
                          right(input,len - i - 1)
                        );
        end if;
    end if;
    set i = i + 1;
end while;
return input;
end; //
delimiter ;

select lower_first('this is my TeSt'); -- tHIS iS mY tEST
```